# Implementing Google Recaptcha V3 - Methods to implement

Tags: recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha, grecaptcha

I am planning to use Google invisible Recaptcha V3 in my application. I want the suggestion by which method I can go. In the developer document, I could see 2 ways,

1. Automatically bind the challenge to a button (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)
2. Programmatically invoke the challenge

for the 2nd option, I know we are doing the server-side validation to check the token from my site and we are getting the scores.

I want to know if I am going to use the 1st option, and how it gets validated from the ReCaptcha server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the 1st option, you just include a submit button inside your form, and you will receive the reCaptcha token in the 'g-recaptcha-response' key from the POST field (e.g.: $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], if you're using php).

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="login" id="loginForm">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" value="">
  <!--Recaptcha button-->
  <button class="g-recaptcha" 
        data-sitekey="#your_site_key" 
        data-callback='onSubmit' 
        data-action='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  function onSubmit(token)
  {
    document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();
  }
</script>
```

Then, validate the token submiting it to "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" as you would do with the 2nd option.

If you are on php, login page from the form's action attribute, would look like this:

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
    "secret"=>"#yourSecretKey"
  , "response"=>$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
  , "remoteip"=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$recaptcha = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
/** $recaptcha:
Array
(
    [success] => 1 // or 0
    [challenge_ts] => 2022-07-16T12:34:38Z
    [hostname] => host // hostname
    [score] => 0.9 // 0.0 to 1.0
    [action] => submit // data-action attribute from reCaptcha button
)
*/
if ($recaptcha["score"] >= 0.5 && $recaptcha["action"] === 'submit')
{
  // action on success
} else {
  // action on false
}
?>
```

About which one to use, I don't know how to answer that... But I guess that both options work similarly, so go with the one that is easier for you to implement.

Comment: About These attributes forthe button
```<button class="g-recaptcha" 
        data-sitekey="#your_site_key" 
        data-callback='onSubmit' 
        data-action='submit'>Submit</button>```
I guess tat we can not customize it more for visual purposes, right? I has already my button with Bootsrap classes, withtype, name, also fontawesome icons, `bg-primary` just to “beauty” the button, but when added all this to the reCAPTCHA button, the button just doesn‘t work. Is this normal? Are there restrictios to use customized button for recaptcha v3?